# Why do I get the error 'Error: Could not find or load main class' when I try to create a docker image using a .JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to create an image from my Spring Boot project and I want to create a Dockerfile, that can create an image of my project.

After a few Google searches, I came across this tutorial from the official documentation.

So I tried to create a file based on it and this is what I got:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY out/artifacts/DWH_WebServices_jar/DWH_WebServices.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

But when running the DockerFile with Intellij, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.business.dwh_webservices.DwhWebServicesApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.business.dwh_webservices.DwhWebServicesApplication
```

So I thought that maybe I was misinforming my class when creating the .JAR, but I did it correctly :

[image]

My class exist as you can see here :

[image]

And here is my `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.business</groupId>
    <artifactId>dwh-webservices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DWH_WebServices</name>
    <description>DWH_WebServices</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your pom.xml. Also how did you generate the jar?

Comment: How did you create the JAR? You must use mvn package

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#package_into_jar) to generate the jar

Comment: Using IDE complicates things, instead build on command line first, e.g. `mvn clean package`. For that to succeed you need proper plugins in place. Docker has nothing to do with your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `mvn package` and it worked !

Thanks to @SimonMartinelli.